# android data transfer rate

Tags: android

how to find  out the data transfer rate while sending and recieving the data from server in android application.

Answer (score 2):

You could add some code within your download/upload code such as for instance:

```
InputStream is = ...;
long totalBytesRead = 0;
long bytesRead = 0;
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while ((bytesRead = is.read(...))!=0) {
    // Do something useful with the bytes you read

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
}

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
float dataRate1 = totalBytesRead / (float) (endTime - startTime); // Bytes/Millisecond
float dataRate2 = dataRate1 * 1000 / 1024.0f; // kiloBytes/second
```

Of course, you could also update periodically the transfer rate within you while loop to get an average rate during the progress.