# Findout Data trasfer rate & Battery consumption in Android app?

Tags: android

I'm working on android app development in which how get profiling information like

1. Data transfer during app running
2. Battery consumption

Is there possible done by code or any API or sample API

Thanks in Advance - sri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go through below link for battery consumtion and data transfer rate . It might helps you.

[Battery consumption.](https://grepular.com/Android_Battery_Graphing_Source_Code)
[Data Transfer rate.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4255270/614807)